# Gnuplot Hypertext in canvas terminal

Tags: cygwin, gnuplot

I'm trying to use the Hypertext functionality in Gnuplot (*Version 5.0 patchlevel 0  last modified 2015-01-01*) which is running in Cygwin/x.

The script (test_script.gp) is taken from the offical gnuplot official documentation (Hypertext section or at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas/ ):

```
#
# Demonstrates how to attach hypertext to points so that
# the text is displayed on mouse-over.
# Not much to see here unless you are using the wxt, svg, qt,
# or HTML5 canvas terminal.
# 
set terminal canvas  solid butt size 600,400 enhanced fsize 10 lw 1     fontscale 1 name "hypertext_1" jsdir "." mousing
#set output 'hypertext.1.js'
unset border
unset key
set encoding utf8
set datafile separator "    "
set size ratio 1 1,1
set noxtics
set noytics
set title "Hypertext is shown when the mouse is over a point" 
Scale(size) = 0.08*sqrt(sqrt(column(size)))
City(String,Size) = sprintf("%s\npop: %d", stringcolumn(String),     column(Size))
GPFUN_Scale = "Scale(size) = 0.08*sqrt(sqrt(column(size)))"
GPFUN_City = "City(String,Size) = sprintf(\"%s\\npop: %d\",     stringcolumn(String), column(Size))"
plot 'cities.dat' using 5:4:(City(1,3)):(Scale(3))      with labels     hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "#ffee99",      'cities.dat' using     5:4:(City(1,3)):(Scale(3))      with labels hypertext point pt 6 ps var lc     rgb "black" lw 0.1
pause -1 "hit return to continue"
set encoding save_encoding
reset
```

Calling this script fromt he cygwin/x teminal as

```
gnuplot -persist test_script.gp
```

does not produce any new window openining but returns in terminal only a sort of translation in html language.
Is there any possibility to have a new gnuplot window with the desired plot showed in it and that makes possible the mouse "hovering" functionality (hypertext) without the need of an html5 browser?

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot has file-based and interactive terminals. The `canvas` terminal is file-based, i.e. gnuplot generates an output file which you must view with an appropriate viewer.

If you want to view the results directly, use an interactive terminal, which do also support the `hypertext` option (at least the `wxt`, `qt` and `windows` terminals, couldn't test `aqua` and `x11`). BTW: This is also what the comment in your example file tells you!

Comment: Thanks Cristoph for the answer. The comment also tells that canvas was supported btw wxt,qt and windows terminals are not showed in the list of terminal I get from 'set terminal' in gnuplot. Any Help?

Comment: If cygwin doesn't provide one of these terminals, you would need to compile gnuplot yourself on cygwin. Or you could use the Windows binaries directly, without cygwin.

Comment: Cay you tell me how to add one of these terminals in cygwin? Where can i find source files or binaries?